# Save mean values by group SAS

Tags: sas

If I have a dataset where x equals 1 or -1, y equals 2 or -2, and z is a random response variable, how could I find the mean of z when x=1, x=-1, y=2, and y=-2 individually? I then want to use the means of each later.  Using proc means, I don't know how to split the data to find the means of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what the CLASS statement does.

```
proc means data=have nway ;
  class x y ;
  var z ;
  output out=want mean=mean_z ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can plot these points such that the mean when x=-1 and x=1 when y=2 are connected and the same for when y=-2?